# Thinking Functionally. Building a New Array in Haskell / Purescript

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, purescript

I'm new to functional programming, and I've decided to build an app in Purescript. I've hit my first hurdle, and I'm not sure how to think about this conceptually.

> I'm not looking for code as much as a way to think functionally about this problem.

I have a list of data. Specifically, something like

```
[ {a :: String, b :: String, c :: String} ]
```

I would like to create a list of `Html` (which is a `purescript-halogen` type) by using the record provided (with a list of the above types).

So, I would have a function

```
buildElements :: forall p i. MyRecordObject -> Array (HTML p i)
```

Now, I think I'm going to need to give this function result type a Monad computational context (purescript `Eff` is like Haskell `IO`)

So something like:

```
buildElements :: forall p i. MyRecordObject -> Eff (Array (HTML p i))
```

My first idea was vaguely around creating a list with something like

```
take $ length xs $ repeat ARecordObject
```

and then map the record over that list, but I wasn't really sure how to translate that into code. It seemed wrong anyway, since my plan involved mutating the state of `ARecordObject`, which is a no-no.

So then I found this function:

```
forEach :: forall e a. Array a -> (a -> Eff e Unit) -> Eff Unit
```

which looks almost perfect! I get an array, I give it a function that somehow assigns the properties in the record to this new array...but no, wait...I'm thinking non-functionally again.

I'm really at a bit of a loss here. Basically, I want to create something like a list of `<li></li>` elements, where I assign properties to each item.

E.g

I'm provided a record with:

```
[ { id: "id1", name: "name1", class: "class1", content: "content1" }
, { id: "id2", name: "name2", class: "class2", content: "content2" } ]
```

And I would like a function `foo` that returns an array:

```
[ li [ id_ rec.id, name_ rec.name, class_ rec.class ] [ text rec.content ]
, li [ id_ rec.id, name_ rec.name, class_ rec.lass ] [ text rec.content ] ]
```

where `rec` is the name of the recordObject (and obviously the two arrays are not identical, but actually mapped over the initial record).

(the dot syntax is a purescript record syntax notation similar to standard getter/setter notation)

Comment: Try to start just by writing a function which takes a single record and returns a single <li> element, suppose it's called `recordToHtml`. Then I think the function you want is `map recordToHtml`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> My first idea was vaguely around creating a list with something like
>
> ```
> take $ length xs $ repeat ARecordObject
> ```
>
> and then map the record over that list, but I wasn't really sure how
>   to translate that into code. It seemed wrong anyway, since my plan
>   involved mutating the state of `ARecordObject`, which is a no-no.

Functional programmers don't just avoid mutation because it's a no-no (indeed, many functional programs make careful use of a controlled dose of mutability) - we do it because it produces safer, simpler code.

To wit: You're thinking in what I call "alloc-init mode", wherein you create some sort of "empty" value and then go about calculating its properties. Forgive my vehemency, but that's a *fundamentally broken* programming model, left over from the days of manual memory management; code which uses it will never be safe and abstractions relying on it will forever be leaky. The idiom doesn't fit into any language that's higher-level than C, and yet, if I had a pound for every time I see code like this...

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo.Bar = new Bar();
foo.Bar.Baz = new Baz();
```

...I would be a rich man (na na na). The default should be to create objects after you know what they're going to look like:

```
var foo = new Foo(new Bar(new Baz()));
```

This is simpler - you're just *calculating a value*, rather than reaching into the memory referenced by a pointer to update its contents - and more importantly it's safer because the type-checker ensures that you haven't forgotten a property and it allows you to make `Foo` immutable. The cleanest imperative code is functional code - you should only be imperative where necessary for performance (or when the language forces your hand).

---

Anyway, rant over. The point is that you're making life harder for yourself than necessary by thinking imperatively. Just write a function that calculates a single `<li>` from a single object...

```
toLi :: MyRecord -> HTML
toLi x = li [ id_ x.id, name_ x.name, class_ x.class ] [ text x.content ]
```

... (note that I'm not somehow creating an "empty" `li` and then populating its values), and then `map` it over your input list.

```
toLis :: [MyRecord] -> [HTML]
toLis = map toLi
```

This is how I'd do it in JS, too, even though I'm not *required* to by the language. No side-effects, no mutation, no need for `Eff` - just simple, safe, purely functional code.

Comment: Thank you very much! Great explanation and the "ah-hah" I needed.